# What is the meaning of "export" in Bash?

Tags: bash, cmd, export, command-line-interface

When I customize my environment, I add `PATH=$PATH:$My-own-Path` in file *.bash_profile*.

The tutorials tell me I should use this one: `export PATH=$PATH:$My-own-Path`

So, what is the difference?

Comment: Also check http://superuser.com/questions/18988/difference-between-a-b-and-export-a-b-in-bash

Comment: @MichaelBurr By the title of the post, I agree that it is a duplicate. But more specifically the OP is asking what's the difference between using `export` explicitly and not using it. Indeed in most situations there will be no difference. Have answered it so.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your exact specific question, in *this particular* case, there isn't ***any*** difference. Why?

Somewhere in the initialization process, the variable `PATH` has already been exported. A change in the variable's value which is already exported does not need another `export`; this is automatic. The processes fired hereafter will get the new value.

Comment: Usually, yes, particularly with `.bash_profile`.  But assuming the environment block is set up is sometimes seen as a security risk.  What if someone ran your script using `env -i`?

Comment: @cdarke The OP is asking about `.bash_profile`. This answer talks specifically and emphatically about _this particular_ case. I don't see any risk if "someone" runs my `.bash_profile` with `env -i`. Please enlighten us if you have a concrete example of security risk or any other significant issues in this context.

Answer (score 1):

`export` makes the environment variable available to child processes

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? E.g., what is the practical upshot of this? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29711813/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash`:

> ... The `export` and `declare -x` commands allow parameters and functions to be added to and deleted from the environment.  If the value of a parameter in the environment is modified, the new value becomes part of the environment, replacing the old.

Also from `man bash`:

> ```
> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
> export -p
> ```
>
> The  supplied  names  are  marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.  If the `-f` option is given, the names refer to functions.  If no names are given, or if the `-p` option is supplied, a list of names of all exported variables is printed.  The `-n` option causes the export property to be removed from each name.  If a variable name is followed by `=word`, the value of the variable is set  to  word. `export` returns an exit status of 0 unless an invalid option is encountered, one of the names is not a valid shell variable name, or `-f` is supplied with a name that is not a function.

Comment: So what is the difference? Can you add a concluding statement? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

Exported variables are available to other programs.  Non-exported variables are not.

Example:

```
$ myVar=Foo             # Create local
$ env | grep '^myVar='
$ export myVar          # Export myVar to child process
$ env | grep '^myVar='
Foo
```

If you want to read more about this, check out [*export*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export) (GNU Bash manual).

Also, please note that non-exported variables will be available to subshells run with `(...)` and other similar notations:

```
$ thereVar=Bar
$ (echo $thereVar; echo $myVar; $myVar=testing; echo $myVar)
Bar
Foo
Testing
$echo $myVar
Foo
```

The subshell cannot affect variables in the parent shell.

For more information on subshells, please reference:

- *[Command Grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping.html)*
- *[Command Execution Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment)*

Comment: *Exported variable are available to other programs*  I think should be qualified.  The environment block is copied to child processes (by default), it is not shared and is not visible to any old process.

Comment: The second link is half-broken - the anchor "#Command-Grouping" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Every process has an area of memory called the *environment block*.  In the environment block are *environment variables*.  These look like ordinary variables, for example `x=42`.

In most shells ([C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) is an exception) you move an ordinary variable into the environment block using `export`.  That command can also create an environment variable without going through an intermediate stage.  If the variable is already in the environment block then `export` will have no effect.

So why?  When a new process is created, the default action is to copy various "core information" from parent to child.  These include the current directory, the umask, the file descriptor table, the uid and gid, and **the environment block**.

Note that the child only gets a *copy* of the parent's environment block. The variable is not shared and cannot be passed back to the parent (except by using some other inter-process communication mechanism).

You can override this default behaviour using the `env` program, but this is rarely required.

So, if we set an environment variable in a shell script using `export` then all our child processes we create, when we call other programs, will get a copy of them.  Some variable names are well-known and have a special meaning, and the `PATH` environment variable is probably the most important of those.

The `PATH` environment variable is used to find programs on UNIX/Linux. Directories in PATH are searched in left-right order each time we need to load a program. Bash also caches executable paths in a `hash` ([KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) calls them "tracked aliases").